# Edwards-Anderson Hamiltonian of a Hopf link

Tags: general-topology, statistical-mechanics

I was calculating the Edwards-Anderson Hamiltonian of a Hopf link. A hopf link is like attachment 1. I have drawn the Seifert surface of that link. The surface is shown in attachment 2. It also contains the Boltzmann weight. So, this is an Ising model. I am confused as there are more than one interaction between a pair of sites. How will I keep that consideration when I calculate the Edwards-Anderson Hamiltonian.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

The attachments cannot be posted as I am a new user. They are available at http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=649548 .

Comment: A quick supplementary question: should I model it as a frustrated Ising system?